# Proper Way To Organize File Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba, file-server

I am setting up a file server using Ubuntu and want to make sure I set up a folder structure that will last.  Where should I be placing everything that I am sharing (Music, Pictures, Videos, etc)?  In theory, if I was setting this up on Windows, I would create a folder directly under C: and set up the different areas of sharing under that (not that that approach would be best either).

**EDIT**

Based on constructive criticism, the question is rather ambiguous.  My question could be restated to ask "Where *shouldn't* I set this up?  Would /usr be an appropriate place to start?  Or would /opt be better?

Comment: Directory structure and organization is more of a personal thing. Everyone organizes their files according to different patterns. This is a very subjective question.

Comment: @MaQleod, I agree, and apologize for the ambiguity.  My question would possibly be better asked if stated "Where shouldn't I set this up?"  I will update the question.

Comment: Does it really matter? Why not simply `/fileshare`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically one would use `/var` or a user's home directory or simply root (/) as the parent of shared directories. `/usr` and `/opt` are not good places because those are generally for programs, libraries, and their supporting files. `/etc` is also not great because that's where configuration files go.

The reasoning behind `/var` is that by convention it is often used for server data files (e.g. Apache, Syslog, etc.) in some distros. But you could also just create a new directory under root.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the Windows approch, you can create a `/home/share` for all users on your system.
Or create `/smb-share` (or somethink else), if you plan to share accross network (Samba).

Comment: `/home/share` is a bad idea (every folder under `/home/` is typically the `home` of a user). I also don't like the idea of cluttering `/` with such things. I'd go with Rob H and say either use `/var/` or, if it is an extra partition, mount it under `/mnt/`.

Comment: My `/smb-share` can be on an extra partition.